# How to export type in typescript, it marks the type as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I need to have my `types` in a separate file, where I create it and export it as default, like so:

```
type props = {
    playerId: string;
    isAutoplayPrevented: boolean;
}

// 'props' is not defined.eslint(no-undef)
export default props;
```

Although I have defined the `props`, I get an ESLint warning that `props` is `undefined`.
Should I ignore that warning and stop ESLint complaint, like so: `// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef`

**Or is there any other more proper solution ?**

Comment: Also check your linter versions because this TS feature (*type-only imports and exports syntax*) is quite new (*TS >= 3.8*). I didn't have that warning with latest versions `"typescript": "^3.8.2"`, `"eslint": "^6.8.0"`,  `"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.20.1-alpha.5"`, though I got another error about `"error  'props' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars"` when was setting a variable using that type.

Answer (score 3):

I offer you to consider a separated file for types and write types like below:

```
export type General = {
  classes: Record<string, string>,
};

export type AxiosCall = {
  // etc
};

// etc
```

For usage you can easily `import` it on other components.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer,
this is a named export.
How i do the default export or you dont suggest default export at all ?

Comment: Dear @TheoItzaris, default exports prevent destructing import and I'm not familiar with it except some cases like creating components. one of my friends told me default export for such these cases causes code duplicity on bundled file but I'm not sure.

Comment: @TheoItzaris, it is best to have a named export as that would allow your code to consistent when importing. Bcoz, with default export, any component importing this type will name it as they wish and I don't, suppose there is way to export default type.